# Где брать реальную интрадей дату c NYSE, CME

Tags: websocket

В интернете не так-то много мест где можно брать апи-дату реальную без задержек, но они все платны, может кто подскажет где можно брать реальную дату по WebSocket с NYSE бесплатно в реальном времени. Ну или самые дешевые варианты.  Пусть даже будет одна акция, главное настроить механизм. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Так если важен механизм, зачем вам реалтайм данные? Не говоря уже о на потоке котировок через websocket без пропусков.

Ну а так посмотрите как работает investing.com если не ошибаюсь там псевдореалтайм котировки...

Comment: но нужно именно полный поток даты со всеми принтами по всем ECN

Comment: Вы бы еще level 2 хотели получить за бесплатно и в реалтайме да и на websocket'ах:) Искренне желаю удачи в ваших поисках. И вы уж извините за мой пессимизм, но я сильно сомневаюсь websocket'ы потянут что то больше чем "типа реалтайм" обновлялку котировок чтобы все красиво мигало... Но я несомненно могу ошибаться.

Comment: ну я платформу не собираюсь писать..так для себя) за ответ спасибо